# How to download bootcamp drivers without using Bootcamp Assistant?

Tags: macos, windows-10, mac, drivers, boot-camp

I am trying to install windows 10 on my Macbook Pro (13" earlier 2015 model) on an external hard drive. I am following [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/218105/is-it-possible-to-use-boot-camp-with-windows-10-from-an-external-hdd/239203#239203?newreg=1cc9ec648d21442580a1e324b1100f79) to make this happen. The 4th step; Preparing the driver drive, says to download Bootcamp drivers using Bootcamp Assistant which is outdated since that is not how Bootcamp looks like anymore. There are no more checks, we simply continue by selecting the windows.iso image file and then partitioning the internal drive and it downloads the Bootcamp drivers itself which are then stored in another partition, which isn't what I want. I want only the Bootcamp drivers for windows 10. Does anybody know how can I get them? I have googled a lot but all videos and blogs are from 2015 which are all outdated.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to install bootcamp the usual way, partitioning internal hard drive and everything, and then cloning that volume to your external drive.

Then delete the partition on you local drive.

Comment: I like the idea. But how can I clone the volume to my  external hard drive?

Comment: http://www.newertech.com/tech_support/manuals/mac/clon_data.php